# What is producing an incorrectly recoded value?

Tags: r, recode

I am using the R version 3.5.1 package sjmisc to perform recodes and produce reports.
Why is the value x = 44 incorrectly recoded into 5?

```
library(sjmisc)
X <- data.frame(x=c(44,14,0,1,4,6,10))
X <- X %>% 
  sjmisc::rec(x,
    rec = "2:5=2 [2-5];6:10=3 [6-10];11:50=4 [11-50];51:max=5 [51+];else=copy",
    as.num = FALSE)
print(X) # x = 44 should have x_r = 4
X %>%  sjmisc::frq(x_r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in the column fall in all the ranges mentioned, it is working.

```
X %>% 
 sjmisc::rec(x,
     rec = "2:5=2 [2-5];6:10=3 [6-10];11:50=4 [11-50];else=copy",
     as.num = FALSE)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#      x x_r  
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1    44 4    
#2    14 4    
#3     0 0    
#4     1 1    
#5     4 2    
#6     6 3    
#7    10 3
```

It could be a bug

Comment: Yes, there does appear to be a bug associated with the max keyword.  Is there a best practice in the R community for reporting function bugs?   Should I contact the package maintainer directly?  What do you suggest?

Comment: @PdV If there is a github page, then you can report it in the issues page.  If they don't have a dev version, you can directly contact the package maintainer